# javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: prefix Rebinding error

Tags: java, soap, soap-client, webservice-client

**Error :**

```
javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: prefix com has been already bound to http://myurl  Rebinding it to http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing is an error
```

I Have below soap request:

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" 
            xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
   <S:Header xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
      <To></To>
      <Action></Action>
      <ReplyTo>
         <Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</Address>
      </ReplyTo>
      <FaultTo>
         <Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</Address>
      </FaultTo>
      <MessageID></MessageID>
   </S:Header>
   <S:Body xmlns="http://www.****.com/ns/2008/03/01/webservices/***/Cache_1" 
   xmlns:ns2="http://www.****.com/ns/2006/05/01/webservices/***/Common_1" 
   xmlns:ns3="http://www.***.com/ns/2006/05/01/webservices/***/Faults_1" 
   xmlns:ns4="http://www.****.com/ns/2006/05/01/webservices/***/QuotesCommon" 
   xmlns:ns5="http://www.***.com/ns/2006/05/01/webservices/***/Quotes_1" 
   xmlns:ns6="http://schemas.****.com/2003/10/Serialization/">
      ********
   </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

I am adding Authorization token in header as below

```
<S:Header xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
      *****
      <com:Authorization xmlns:com="http://myurl">
         <com:ApplicationID>******</com:ApplicationID>
         <com:Token>*******</com:Token>
      </com:Authorization>
   </S:Header>
```

java code in handler to add authorization token in header

```
SOAPHeader header = envelope.getHeader();
SOAPElement authorization = header.addChildElement("com:Authorization");
                authorization.addNamespaceDeclaration("com", "http://myurl");  
                SOAPElement applicationID =  authorization.addChildElement("com:ApplicationID");
                applicationID.addTextNode("*******");
                SOAPElement token = authorization.addChildElement("com:Token");
                token.addTextNode("*****");
```

**I am facing Error :**

```
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: prefix com has been already bound to http://myurl. Rebinding it to http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing is an error
```

The Authorization header tag i got before sending request is below

```
<com:Authorization xmlns:com="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
   <com:ApplicationID>*****</com:ApplicationID>
   <com:Token />
</com:Authorization>
```

Waiting for response

Answer (score 0):

**I applied Below Code and it works for me**

SOAPElement authorization = header.addChildElement("Authorization","","http://www.reuters.com/ns/2006/05/01/webservices/rkd/Common_1");

**This Gives me Authorization header as below:**

```
<Authorization xmlns="http://www.reuters.com/ns/2006/05/01/webservices/rkd/Common_1">
    <ApplicationID>********</ApplicationID>
   <Token>*******</Token>
</Authorization>
```